# How to use CASE and SUBSTRING_INDEX in doctrine query?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-query

I have a sql query which is succesfully running in the mysql server and got the output.

But I couldn't able to convert this query in the doctrine format.
Query is as below

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN seqnum < 10 THEN domain ELSE 'Others' END) as domain,
       SUM(c)
FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(email, INSTR(email, '@') + 1), '.', 1) as domain,
             COUNT(*) as C,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM newsletter_recipient
      WHERE LENGTH(email) > 0
      GROUP BY domain
     ) d
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN seqnum < 10 THEN domain ELSE 'Others' END)
ORDER BY SUM(c) DESC;
```

When i am using this in doctrine it give errors like

> Expected known function, got 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'

Hope someone could help me to convert this query in doctrine format.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to [implement vendor-specific functions](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/docs/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.rst#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language) so that DQL can translate it into proper SQL calls, or in this simple case a combination of built-in function calls might be enough:

```
SUBSTRING(email, LOCATE('@', email) + 1, ...
```

For a full list of available cross-platform functions, [see the docs](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/docs/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.rst#dql-functions).

Also I cannot resist to mention that the domain name without the TLDs might contain dots, for example you might look for `mail.example` in `info@mail.example.org`. Up to your specifications, though.